# Ideas for Print in a PHP System

Tags: php, printing

im making a backend but i need to print out tickets in POS Printers, so i will explain why im asking

1.- long time ago a friend had a server (10.0.0.1) and client computers (10.0.0.2 , 10.0.0.3, etc)
so i was watching that their php POS was hosted in the LAN server so how they was printing?

2.- In the client machines (in the same lan) each machine was running wamp wit a *.txt file with the margins of the tickets and one php script called print.php so when they was asking the server (10.0.0.1) to print they was printing locally

any ideas how to achieve this? i was playing with Mike 42 ESC-Pos and runs fine but for print on a network im watching that needs the printers running on LAN or by Netbios

warm regards and thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe this might help you: https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php. Or are you already using this? Since you say `i was playing with Mike 42 ESC-Pos`. Is this the device or library above?

Comment: Hi! yes i was playing with it but as i read in the FAQ i need the printers on SMB or know the ip for a deploy of 2 or 3 workstations will be fine but if i need to deploy in more machines i think will be difficult

Comment: It may be me, but I dont think I understand your specific question anymore. You want to print something on a Mike 42 ESC-Pos printer with PHP right? But trough the network or local? I think local for testing would be your first target anyway. Then after, test trough network.

Comment: Hi! ok let me explain i was using the mike42 Esc-POS for test it and locally in the server works fine, im just asking for an idea if i need to deploy 7 POS over different floors of the building how will be the good way to identify and send each pos to work with

Comment: Solved! in the end we make a routine in the control panel to set the printers via SMB to identify which one it is which one